# How to store and get data from database on static server using android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a android app for notice board..
In which I want store notice on server trough myapp and also I want to get same notice in same app.
So help me for how to store data in static server database on internet using android  app and how to get in any android app

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Now that you have consciously clicked the button "Ask Question" but didn't ask anything, please [take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and actually *ask a question concerning a concrete problem*. Only then we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a REST webservice on your server and have your Android app invoke RESTful methods on your server. Google around there are hundreds of examples.

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-part-1/